# How to find the area and perimter of a rectangle that has two points defined?

Tags: python

I have a Point class and Rectangle class set up, here is the code for that:

```
import math

class Point:
    """A point in two-dimensional space."""

    def __init__(self, x: float = 0.0, y: float = 0.0)->None:               
        self.x = x
        self.y = y    


    def moveIt(self, dx: float, dy: float)-> None:
        self.x = self.x + dx
        self.y = self.y + dy    

    def distance(self, otherPoint: float): 
        if isinstance(otherPoint, Point):
            x1 = self.x
            y1 = self.y
            x2 = otherPoint.x
            y2 = otherPoint.y

            return ( (x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 )**0.5    


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft = Point(0,0), bottomRight = Point(1,1)):
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight
```

The two points are the top left and the bottom right for the rectangle. How could I find the area and perimeter of this rectangle from two points? Would appreciate any and all help!

Comment: If you drew a rectangle and placed the top left corner at position (3, 10) and the bottom right corner at  (9, 4) what is the area and perimeter of the rectangle? Can you generalize the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can access the x and y values of each point and calculate the height and width, from there we can create methods that calculate area and perimeter

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, topLeft = Point(0,0), bottomRight = Point(1,1)):
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight
        self.height = topLeft.y - bottomRight.y
        self.width = bottomRight.x - topLeft.x
        self.perimeter = (self.height + self.width) * 2
        self.area = self.height * self.width

rect = Rectangle(Point(3,10),Point(4,8))
print(rect.height)
print(rect.width)
print(rect.perimeter)
print(rect.area)
```

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/9.24$ python3.7 rect.py
> 2
> 1
> 6
> 2
> ```

Or using methods

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, topLeft = Point(0,0), bottomRight = Point(1,1)):
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight
        self.height = topLeft.y - bottomRight.y
        self.width = bottomRight.x - topLeft.x

    def make_perimeter(self):
        self.perimeter = (self.height + self.width) * 2
        return self.perimeter

    def make_area(self):
        self.area = self.height * self.width
        return self.area

rect = Rectangle(Point(3,10),Point(4,8))
print(rect.height)
print(rect.width)
print(rect.make_perimeter())
print(rect.make_area())
```

Comment: Thank you. When I tried that it said: TypeError: 'Point' object does not support indexing

Comment: When I run that code, I get: self.height = topLeft[1] - bottomRight[1]

TypeError: 'Point' object does not support indexing

Comment: @JoshB0 updated working, not you can also make methods instead of initalizing them

Comment: Thanks so much! when I make a blank rectangle, r1 = Rectangle() and call print(r1.make_area, r1.make_perimter) it gives me: <bound method Rectangle.make_area of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x000002B7D806E278>>

Comment: Is there a way to have it print area and perimeter for the default Point(0,0) and Point(1,1)?

Comment: Yeah just create your instance as `rect = Rectangle()`

Comment: @JoshB0 oops sorry was on iphone didn't see your previous comment will check for solution now

Comment: @JoshB0 Oh if you are going to use the route where you are calling the methods you must call them as `r1.make_perimeter()` its a function that returns a value not a variable

Comment: @JoshB0 also note the math on your defaults is going to come out strange since, your top y is less than your bottom y, not sure why you have those values as such but that will be why you produce a perimeter of 0 and area of -1

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything is perfect!

Comment: @JoshB0 haha aweome I learned here too had to do a little research to solve but glad it worked out, Cheers!